issue in hypertuning svc that shows solver terminated early
`param_grid={'select__k':randint(1,16),            
'svc__C':loguniform(1e-4,1e4),            
'svc__kernel':['linear','poly','rbf','sigmoid'],            
'svc__degree':randint(1,10),            
'svc__tol':loguniform(1e-5,1e-1),            
'svc__class_weight':[None,'balanced'],            
'svc__max_iter':randint(5000,10000),            
'svc__decision_function_shape':['ovr','ovo']} 
pipeline=Pipeline([('select',SelectKBest()),                   
('svc',SVC())]) 
search_svc=RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline,                              
param_grid,                              
n_iter=100,                              
cv=5,                              
scoring='accuracy',                              
return_train_score=True,                              
random_state=32) 
search_svc.fit(x_resample, y_resample) 
best_estimator = search_svc.best_estimator_ 
svc_results = cross_val_score(best_estimator, x_resample, y_resample, cv=5, return_train_score=True) print('Train score =', svc_results.mean())`

result:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py:299: ConvergenceWarning: Solver terminated early (max_iter=9660).  Consider pre-processing your data with StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler.
warnings.warn(
hypertuned solver to be runned successfully

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
